# Tool/ workaround for testing locally stored Webpage on iPhone

Tags: iphone, tools, usability-testing

I need to test a webpage on iPhone. Due to some security/IT regulations, I'm not allowed to use cloud services (especially US-based 8-) , because I'm working for a big company in Europe). So I'm looking for a way to store my webpage on the iPhone and enter it locally (and avoiding Internet access). 
I already managed it for Android by use of Firefox browser.

**-> Does someone know a testing tool for accessing a locally stored webpage on iPhone?**

**-> Or does someone know a way to test a webpage on iPhone avoiding cloud/Internet access?**

*I have already seen Offline Browser in iTunes store, but this app looks suspicious.*

Answer (score 1):

My route for this was to install XAMPP on a local desktop/laptop, change the settings to allow outside connections, and access the webpage through the local network.

It's a bit of a pain, but if anyone is interested I can post a walkthrough.

Comment: This is the obvious answer, spin up a local webserver with XAMPP or WAMP and browse to it on your local network

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to locally store the page on the iPhone.

Since you could just run a simple webserver on your local desktop machine so you can access your webpage through localhost on there (no internet access required, you only need to be on the same network). Then you can just call the IP of that local desktop machine on your iPhone or any other device to visit your webpage.

Some more infos: [How do you access a localhost website from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132105/how-do-you-access-a-website-running-on-localhost-from-iphone-browser)

And a really great tool is [quirktools.com/screenfly/](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/) (but needs internet access only to call this site), then you can also call webpages only available from your local network.

Comment: Storing the site on iPhone is more convenient during test sessions: No tech worries, no setup stuff - just reach over the iPhone. Anyway I'm looking for WiFi stuff as plan B. Thanks for this tip.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to just EMULATE the device? I cannot see a reason you would want to store the webpage on the iPhone.

To emulate, why not use Chrome Developer Tools?

This provides a "view" of what the site would look like on different devices. But is not an EXACT representation.

Right click on the page > Inspect

[image: Right click, inspect]

Then click the "Responsive" button and you will be able to emulate different devices

[image]

A couple of other questions, so I can evaluate further.

Is the site live and public facing?
What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As said above I wanted to test a webpage - sort of high fidelity mockup. And user test it running on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit of overkill for your needs but it's worth mentioning.

Ludei  makes a tool called [Cocoon JS](https://www.ludei.com/cocoonjs/) for wrapping up HTML5 apps in a native container with special enhancements for HTML5 canvas and WebGL (and much more)... But as part of their tooling they enable you to "upload" a zip file of your page and all related assets for testing on your device.

With this you could upload your content then run it (full screen) via their Cocoon Dev mobile app.

I should note there is one minor thing to be aware of (only in dev mode)... Since you need to be able to exit your content (to reload or switch content/settings) there is a little "X" put in the top right corner so you can break out... Thus if you were hoping to create a seamless "indistinguishable from native" app feel this "X" will be odd.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Ghostlab](https://www.vanamco.com/ghostlab/) for this, myself. While it's not free, it does have a free trial. I can access any localhost or Virtual Host URLs as long as my laptop is on the same network as my iPhone, either by typing in the URL on my phone, or by using the QR code.

It allows me to use the developer tools to inspect/modify things, and see those effects on my iPhone at the same time. It also works for allowing me to look at it on the desktop while a user looks at it on the phone.